# Is 'a.k.a.' an acceptable abbreviation to use in academic writing?

Tags: abbreviations

Is it sometimes (or ever) acceptable to use in academic writing the abbreviation 'a.k.a.' ('also known as')?

Comment: I'd avoid it, but which academic field are you referring to? Conventions do vary.

Comment: In one word: no. If you write it out in full, possibly.

Comment: Depending on the context, consider using i.e. instead.

Answer (score 16):

If you're using it "literally" (i.e. - to specify an alternative name *used naturally by [at least **some**] other people* for the thing you're talking about) then it should be fine in most formal contexts. Except where the alternative designation itself is inherently informal (e.g. *G W Bush aka "Dubya"*), where it's a matter of whether mentioning the alternative *name* is appropriate, rather than ***aka***.

What's *not* okay in academic contexts is the informal use of ***aka*** to introduce an ad-hoc alternative term purely to *describe/characterise* something - such as, for example, [*Houston's new Astrodome, aka. the Eighth Wonder of the World*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KTT0Y45jWIwC&q=%22aka%20the%20eighth%20Wonder%20of%20the%20World%22&dq=%22aka%20the%20eighth%20Wonder%20of%20the%20World%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PPlUVOP4G6nd7Qa38oHgCQ&redir_esc=y).

---

The above link includes a *single* period after ***aka***, which I would say is *never* "correct". But although there are twice as many written instances of ["[Alcatraz] Island, also known as The Rock"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22til%20morning%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22island%20also%20known%20as%20the%20rock%22), if you check [the abbreviated usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22til%20morning%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22island%20a.k.a.%20the%20rock%22) it seems to me most writers *don't* include periods.

Answer (score 11):

Wikipedia Manual of Style, for one:

> **a.k.a. AKA** Should only be used in small spaces. Otherwise use the full phrase. … Never use *aka.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Abbreviations

Answer (score 2):

No. A.k.a. is formal enough for police reports and journalism that covers the "crime beat." It has a specialized meaning appropriate to public statements about criminal aliases.